# Does a second One hit obliterator object actually exist?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I was looking at the [BOTW object map](https://objmap.zeldamods.org/) for Lynels, but decided to search for the One hit obliterator.

However, what made me gasp is that 2 of them were found: One in the shrine of resurrection and one nearby Divine beast Vah Ruta.

Does this second instance of the One Hit Obliterator ACTUALLY exist, or is it just an object map bug?

Comment: Could you edit the question to add the filters you applied to your search? I can't seem to find what you are looking at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't exist as an object you can pick up, but warping to Divine Beast vah Ruta and looking up for a whille allows you to see it when it falls.

Comment: This..... Is most likely what it was. Yep.

Answer (score 2):

### There is no instances of the OHO beyond the one granted in the DLC, found in the Shrine of Resurrection.

That said, there are glitches that allow you to *keep* the OHO after the end of the trial.

> **Mini Game Storage: Keep the One Hit Obliterator**
>
> Effect: Lets you keep the One Hit Obliterator outside the quest it's meant to be used in
>
> How To: Activate mini game storage with the Test of Wood escape glitch mentioned above, then start the Obliterator trial. You'll immediately fail the mini game due to having unequipped the Forest Dweller's Sword in favour of the One Hit Obliterator. Now, choose to restart the mini game. Monk Maz Koshia will say you've left the Great Plateau and that the trial has ended, but he won't take the Obliterator away. Instead, he'll take your current weapon, which is now the Forest Dweller's Sword. You'll then fail the Test of Wood again, and still have the One Hit Obliterator in your inventory, letting you use it whenever you want or hang it up in your house.
>
> Notes: The One Hit Obliterator only does one damage outside of the Great Plateau, but will reduce Link to a quarter of a heart when used regardless. Dying with it equipped will not cause an instant game over either, and both Fairies and Mipha's Grace will now act as expected when using it.

[Source](https://zelda.gamepedia.com/Glitches_in_Breath_of_the_Wild#Mini_Game_Storage:_Keep_the_One_Hit_Obliterator)

As for the Object Map, this is a tool built from data mining the game's code - outside of this tool, there is no records anywhere of a "second instance" of the OHO - likely making it a bug in the tool's code.

Comment: Another reason to explain how it could simply be a bug in the tool is that if you do a search for “One-Hit Obliterator”, it does pull up two results; however despite showing the two locations the OP mentioned, they reference the same “actor”(?) key. So likely whoever built the tool mis-linked a single item to two locations

Comment: Yep, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Without giving away any spoilers, the short answer is [yes it does exist](https://zelda.gamepedia.com/One-Hit_Obliterator). Now for the spoilers...

> The One-Hit Obliterator is more of a quest item than it is an
>  obtainable weapon. Once you have downloaded the Champion's Ballad DLC,
>  you should get a quest where Zelda basically tells you to return the
>  Sheikah slate to the Shrine of Resurrection. Doing this gives you the
>  OHO. However, upon taking it, the game locks you into a quest. 4
>  area's will now be highlighted in the Great Plateau, and you now have
>  to go and beat all of the enemies at each location. Once you do, the
>  OHO splits into 4 blue orbs which ultimately leads you to 4 areas near
>  the divine beasts. There's then a bunch more to the Champion's Ballad
>  story (and I HIGHLY recommend completing it), but the OHO can no
>  longer be obtained; it will just be at the Shrine of Resurrection,
>  although you can't take it anymore.

> I would like to also say while the OHO sounds amazing, it limits you
>  to only being able to take one hit before dying. Plus, it only can do
>  2 hits in a row before it needs to recharge for a bit. This honestly
>  makes it pretty impractical when facing a ton of enemies, which you
>  will once you get to that point in the quest.

Comment: Um, wrong answer. I KNOW about the One hit obliterator, but I am asking about the entity by Vah Ruta. IS that an OHO?

Comment: @Eristheguest You may want to clarify your title and question. Upon first glance, the question seems to be asking about the OHO existence as a whole. It wasn't until I read it a few times did I understand you were asking about the [object map](https://objmap.zeldamods.org/#/map/z3,0,0) (a source outside BOTW)

Comment: It may not be the answer you were looking for, but its the answer thats true. You asked "does this actually exist" which doesn't particularly specify that you wanted to know if the instance by Vah Ruta actually exists. Hence why my answer is what it is. I'd suggest editing your question to make it more understandable of what you really want.

Comment: @Wondercricket Ohhh I see now. I also did not realize the OP was asking about some other interactive map outside of the main game map. My question now would be, is it off topic? Does it really pertain to the game if its some external source? How could we answer if its bugged or not?

Comment: I added the map, and ill clarify: Does the one hit obliterator object by vah ruta exist in the object map exist? If yes, how would I get to it, with glitches being available?